# Wordpress Persistent connection rule does not work for "posts"

Tags: php, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

```
add_action( 'init', 'rule' );

function rule() {

        add_rewrite_rule(
            '^(en|fr|de|ru)/(.?.+?)/?$',
            'index.php?lang=$matches[1]&pagename=$matches[2]',
            'top'
        );    
}
```

The code above is part of all my code.
First of all, I must say, my code works on everything else. **(Date, Category, Label, etc.)**

Even the code above works fine for "`post_type=page`" ie page type. However, if "`post_type=post`" is entered,

It automatically redirects "`localhost/en/hello-world`" to "`localhost/hello-world`". But it works fine if a page like "`localhost/en/contact`" is entered.

- "`Localhost/en/category/food`"
- "`Localhost/en/2019/08/28`"
- "`Localhost/en/tag/food`"

I don't make sense of why a "`post`" doesn't work when thats are working properly.

Who knows, maybe I should write separate rules for "**`page`**" and "**`post`**". and!

**I tried:**

```
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^(en|fr|de|ru)/(.?.+?)/?$',
        'index.php?lang=$matches[1]&pagename=$matches[2]&post_type=posts',
        'top'
    );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^(en|fr|de|ru)/(.?.+?)/?$',
        'index.php?lang=$matches[1]&pagename=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
```

but again I didn't get a result. I don't know if I add any *"custom_post_type"* to the same problem.

I am looking forward to your thoughts and solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Does it load on the correct URL but immediatley redirect? Or does it not match the rule at all? It sounds like the canonical redirect, but you can test the rule works with a plugin such as monkey rewrite rule tester

Comment: `pagename` URL parameter is used for slug of the page (post type `page`), for slug of the "blog" post (post type `post`) `name` URL parameter is used, in case of custom post type the name of URL parameter is the post type slug. Respectively: `?lang=$matches[1]&pagename=$matches[2]`, `?lang=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]`, `?lang=$matches[1]&cpt_slug=$matches[2]`.

Comment: @nmr thanks. I 'll try it now.

Comment: @nmr Thank you so much. Now it worked perfectly. Add your answer below and I'll check it. `add_rewrite_rule(
         '^(en|fr|de|ru)/([^/]+)/?$',
         'index.php?lang=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]',
         'top'
     );`